# Ethereum transaction with multi input and multi output like bitcoin

Tags: transactions, ether, accounts, multisignature

What happens to my wallet when I only `1000 accounts` with `0.0001 ether` and the `tx-fee` is about the same, I can't spend anything anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. You need to pay transaction fee for each transaction and one transaction can only tranfer assets from one account. Or if the origin account is actually a smart contract then it can transfer to multiple accounts in the same transaction.

Ethereum is not meant for such use - if you need similar (UTXO) functionality you should write a smart contract for handling the assets. Then you simply sends all the assets to the contract and the contract keeps some sort of track of the assets' origins.

Comment: Thanks, So assume I have a site and I want to give unique address to each my users that generated by an HD wallet. If per user send a little amount to his/her address, I can't spend them, so bad. Do I need to generate a smart contract to get ether? Does have only one address per smart contract? How do I know which user send ether for me?

Comment: A contract has one address. If you have further questions please post a new question